# CMake: how to create a CMakeLists.txt that runs ./configure once? 

Tags: cmake, googletest

How do I create a CMakeLists.txt for gmock to configure only once?

I tried:

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET( gmock DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gmock-1.6.0/lib/.libs/libgmock.a COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gmock-1.6.0 && ./configure && make )

but this will do a ./configure every single time, even when I really only need to run it once.

As an aside, I'm open to using FIND_PACKAGE(), etc... for the long run so I don't need to make changes when updating gtest, but at this point, I'm just trying to get it to build without configuring every single time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to have a build dependency on gtets or gmock source? If so, this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/googletestframework/zHy-rrKz_Ho/xJNkzm14UskJ) on gtest mailing list may help. In short, simply `ADD_DIRECTORY` with your gtest or gmock source code and then you can depend on public library targets defined there.

Answer (score 1):

Split the configure and the make call of gmock into two separate custom_targets and don't forget to add a dependency to each of them.

That is for the configure-target maybe the configure.in or any other file from gmock which makes it necessary to re-run configure and the configure-target to the make-target.

Then the make-target should be in dependency to one of your targets and not to the libgmock.a (which is generated by the make call).

HTH